# Where can I find statistics about deleted questions related to Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-questions, statistics

For my research, I need statistics on deletions between July 1 2013 and March 4 2019 related to Stack Overflow questions. Since the repositories do not contain deleted questions and this data is not available except for the moderators, I would like to request it from you.

I found a post where the statistics related to 2014 was provided, but I need the data for the whole period mentioned.

The purpose of these statistics is to estimate the valid distribution of the quality of questions posted to Stack Overflow.

I would be grateful if the statistic contain the reasons for the deletion as well.

Comment: On MSO - *"1,452,928 posts were deleted on Stack Overflow during the year of 2019."*. From *[What posts get deleted, and why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why/296609#296609)*.

Answer (score 3):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) has *some* information about deleted posts; [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1246738/number-of-deleted-and-non-deleted-questions?fromDate=2013-07-01&tillDate=2019-03-04) says

- 17.3M questions have been asked in that period
- 5.3M of those questions are currently deleted

Deletion reasons aren't recorded there; almost all information about deleted posts is stripped (spam/rude/abusive flags are one of the exceptions; still, having such a flag doesn't mean it's *deleted* for that reason).